# How to integrate Azure DevOps Server (on-premise) to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, azure-devops-server-2019

I have installed Azure DevOps Server 2019 on a standalone server for evaluation purpose. I would like to assign some domain users (e.g. mydomain\tester1). This standalone server is not joining any domain.

My question is how can I integrate Azure DevOps Server with existing Active Directory? Should I join the server to domain or I can setup in the application settings? There are very few reference about Azure DevOps. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to **join the server** which installs Azure DevOps **to Active Directory**.

That's all required. After this, you could directly add domain users or groups to groups in Azure DevOps.

> There are very few reference about Azure DevOps (server).

You could also refer TFS related article and blog. TFS is the previous name of Azure DevOps on-premise Server. Most of the server side configuration hasn't changed since the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible not to join the server?  Because our company policy not allow test server join the company domain.

Comment: @Mark It's not able to do this. If you do not join the server to any Active Directory. You are only able to add windows /local users to Azure DevOps on that server.

Comment: Hi Patrick, one more question. Without joining the server to AD, how can I authenticate my Git client (like TortiseGit) to the Azure DevOps server using the local users?

Comment: @Mark Not sure if you mean you want to use this kind of Git Repo during the build. Here is a full list of supported repo. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops . In the get source select add other GIT. There will be a pop up dialog, there is a generic Git Service connection, you need to add your git repo url,  User name /Password /Token key.